# why would i want to use a devexpress gridview as opposed to the one asp.net has?

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I believe that one needs to buy a license(?) to use devexpress. I'm currently implementing a gridview and want the sorting arrows to appear in column headers. I know that devexpress grids have that feature and I believe many more? Could anyone point out any specific reason why someone would pay for using a devexpress grid, or I guess the devexpress suite comes with a lot more than just grids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Could anyone point out any specific reason why someone would pay for using a devexpress grid, or I guess the devexpress suite comes with a
>   lot more than just grids?**

*[Here is your reason](http://blog.beleringenierie.com/2011/06/interet-des-controles-tierce-partie/?lang=en) of paying for the third party controls, In Short features give preference to use these rather than the standard controls.*

it’s unlikely for the client to have a specific request about some user interface component that can’t be satisfied with either default controls or 3rd party controls. Many of the convenience aspects like detailed view, sorting, auto completion, filtering, and changing perspective have already been solved by the 3rd party companies over the several versions of the controls.

When in need for some UI functionality, it’s better to search the companies’ websites for something suitable, instead of trying to develop from scratch. It will also certainly be cheaper than going over the document, develop, debug, test, and deploy cycle countless times.

By using 3rd party controls it’s easier to keep focus on the actual business functionality for your project, to spend time developing visible features for the application, than to work on solving the many background technical difficulties associated with developing every functional request.

On the other hand, if you reach the conclusion that the control would require some serious modifications in order to suit your needs, it’s probably better to do the entire development in house, eventually based on the simple default controls that come with the .NET Framework.

> For example, I do use devexpress controls, on which project i am
>   working they specially require a developer with knowledge of
>   DevExpress control, because that will reduce the development time(
>   Project completion Time also) rather than using the standard control.
>   The Specific requirement make them to pay for the controls as those
>   guys commented in this SO thread.

Check these for feature comparison - [Standard GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/cc163933.aspx) vs [DevExpress GridView](http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/ASP/Grid/). I like it's client side functionality..

Answer (score 1):

Here's a reason.  Because they want sorting arrows in column headers.  Also, any of hundreds of other features these products provide that the default grid does not.

The point is, the extra features ARE the specific reason.

Comment: Well, offcourse the arrows would be one reason, but this can be implemented manually to emulate. I'm sure it has a ton of other functionality and cool features, but for someone who hasn't used this, your answer tells me nothing more than my question. I was looking more for some details that would help me understand some major differences or what else comes in this suite besides grid functionality.

Comment: offten it's much cheaper to buy that features with 3rd party components like DevExpress GridView then to develop it

Comment: @neuDev33 - They have an entire website devoted to explaining the features they provide.  We can't do it justice here.  And we're not the DevExpress marketing website.  On YOU can decide if it offers some value for you.  All features these tools provide could be implemented manually, but Most people buy these tools because they don't want to implement various features themselves.  And, as Antonio mentions, it may cost less to buy than to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Not only does it take care of operations such as sorting and search. It is actually very useful in helping you populate data from your database easily by quickly mapping your fields to IQueryables (If you are using C# and not DevExtreme). If you're using the grid on many pages in your platform, you can easily configure all these grids from one single point (Themes, Functionality, Configuration, etc...). It also provides additional security measures to prevent certain injection attacks. Finally, it is always updated with new features and improvements with constant releases. One really important thing too is that the DevExpress help center and forums are very rich and you will find an answer for almost any question or issue you come across. So using the DevExpress component will bring scalability and increase reliability with time for your platform.